# Calculating average of all user input numbers using while loops in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work through a problem presented in one of my classes. The prompt is telling us to get the user to enter any numbers (can be positive, negative, or 0), while ignoring non-numeric inputs. Then we need to compute and display the average of all the numbers entered by the user. If the user doesn't give any numbers, I need to output "you didn't enter any numbers".

My main issue is that I'm not able to store and add the numbers given by the user properly. I'm fairly certain that everything before and after the while statement is sound. So, I know the issue must lie within `while (enter!="Yes"||enter!="yes"||enter!="Y"||enter!="y")`, but I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. Since I have variables for my average, the sum of the user given numbers, and a counter to keep track of loop iterations, I'm pretty sure my troubles are coming from my code not being in the correct order.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter any numbers, then type Yes to continue.");
        string enter = Console.ReadLine();
        string msg = "";
        decimal average;
        int counter = 0;
        decimal sum = 0;
        bool res = decimal.TryParse(enter, out average);
        while (enter!="Yes"||enter!="yes"||enter!="Y"||enter!="y")
        {
            sum = decimal.Parse(enter);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter any numbers, then type Yes to continue");
            enter = Console.ReadLine();
            sum += counter;
            counter++;
        }
        average = sum / counter;
        msg = (res) ? $"The sum of your numbers is {average}" : "You didn't enter any numbers";
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a `while` loop? A `do while` loop might be more appropriate here. Also, why are you instructing the user to type "yes" when they are done entering values? Why not have them type "stop" or "done"?

Comment: We haven't covered `do while` in my class yet. We might actually get to that later in the week. I've also changed my sentinel value to `while (enter!="Done"||enter!="done")`.

Comment: You should 'read' the statements inside the while loop out loud to see if they/their order makes sense. (its a real thing called [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) and/or fire up the [free, awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: Better yet, write `pseudo-code` to develop the logic for your program before you start writing your program. Doubt that you'll cover `do-while` later in your class-you're expected to look at the necessary documentation and to perform additional research on your own. It's very similar to a `while`-you just check the condition at the end of the loop instead of the beginning. `Do-While` executes at least once, whereas `While` may execute zero or more times.

Comment: replace your logical ORs with logical ANDs (`enter` needs to not be "Yes" and not be "yes" and not be...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just posted an update with some code I wrote that solved my problem.

Comment: Please do not include answer into the question. If you no longer have a question feel free to delete your post (note so that deleting post with answers known to be weighted a lot by the question ban algorithm), if you have an answer post it as answer. I reverted the invalid edit.

Comment: Try `while (enter!="Yes" && enter!="yes" && enter!="Y" && enter!="y")`.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
static void Main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    decimal sum = 0;
    bool exit=false;    
    do 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter any number or type \"done\" to exit");
        var enter = Console.ReadLine();
        if (enter.Trim().ToLower() != "done")
        {
            var ok = decimal.TryParse(enter, out var num);
            if(!ok) continue;
            sum += num;
            counter++;
        } else exit=true;
        
    } while (!exit);
    
     var average = counter > 0 ? sum / counter:0;
     var msg = average>0?  $"The average  of your numbers is {average}" : "You didn't enter any numbers";
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative for you to play with. Just to give you some more ideas.

```
string enter = "";
string[] stop = new [] { "yes", "y" };
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
while (!stop.Contains(enter.ToLowerInvariant()))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter any numbers, then type Yes to continue.");
    enter = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(enter, out int number))
    {
        numbers.Add(number);
    }
}
if (numbers.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The average of your numbers is {numbers.Average()}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter any numbers");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this......

```
    string enter = "";
    string msg = "";
    decimal average;
    int counter = 0;
    decimal sum = 0;
    decimal input;
    
    while (enter!="Yes"&&enter!="yes"&&enter!="Y"&&enter!="y")
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter any numbers, then type Yes to continue");
            enter = Console.ReadLine();
            bool res = decimal.TryParse(enter, out input);
            if (res) { 
                sum += input;
                counter++;
            }
    }
    if (counter != 0)
    {
        average = sum / counter;
        msg = $"The average of your numbers is {average}";
    }
    else {
        msg = "You didn't enter any numbers";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(msg);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```