# While loop doesnt function when calculatin all positive numbers c#

Tags: c#

I am making a `while` loop. The purpose of the loop is to take all the positive numbers and calculating the average. It works *most of the time* but *not always*. Can someone help? here is the code:

```
double count = 0;
int sum = 0;
int input = -1;

while (input != 0)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (input > 0)
    {
        sum += input;
        count++;
    }

    if (input < 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

if (input == 0)
{
    Console.Write($"Average of all positive numbers is: { (sum += input) / count:0.00} ");
}
```

Comment: When does it work and when doesn't it work?

Comment: Why are you getting twice the user input in the loop? Why isn't that input treated for the sum calculation?

Comment: are you looking for running average of all numbers entered so far, and if number entered is zero, the loop should exit? trying to understand your requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating average of all user input numbers using while loops in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715778/calculating-average-of-all-user-input-numbers-using-while-loops-in-c-sharp)

Comment: if you straight away input 0 you will get a divide by zero exception. use Math.Max(count, 1) to at least divide by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second if is redundant it should work just like this

```
while (input != 0) {
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (input > 0)
    {
        sum += input;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Your problem was when you enter a negative number it gives you the option to enter another, but then you enter a new iteration of the while loop and it asks you to enter another number. Removing the second if should fix your problem. Hope i helped :)

Comment: it still throws when a non number is entered

Comment: yes it does, but it should throw since the user is expected to enter a number

Comment: is it supposed to crash when the first integer entered is a zero?

Comment: keeping `sum` as `int` is a *dangerous practice*: if I try to find out the average of one and two *billions* (`1000000000` and `2000000000`) I'll get the very wrong result because of *integer overflow*

Comment: @Dimitry Bychenko having said that: you better use a long instead of a double since a double has a greater range but lacks precision.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not throw exceptions when non numeric data is entered

```
    int count = 0;
    long sum = 0;
    int input;
    
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        if (input > 0)
        {
            sum += input;
            count++;
        }
    }   
    
    Console.Write($"Average of all positive numbers is: {sum} / {Math.Max(count,1.0)} = {Math.Round( sum / Math.Max(count,1.0), 2)}.");
```

Comment: Why do you need `continueLoop` at all? `while(true)` and `else break;` are more readable

Comment: indeed! fixed it

Comment: you, probably, want `if (input == 0) break;`

Comment: just press enter (no input) or enter a non numeric character will end the loop.